# Grail Deep XML Conversion

Tags: xml, grails, groovy, grails-2.4

I have recently upgraded a Grails project to use version `2.4.4` from `1.3.7`. After this upgrade I have an issue with XML conversion of the objects.

In my code I have used converter as:

```
import grails.converters.XML

def converter = policy as XML
String xml = converter.toString()
```

My Policy.groovy has below fields:

```
String policyNumber
String policyOrigin

static hasMany = [sources:Source, regions:Region]
```

In Grails `1.3.7`, the converted XML had tags for the direct fields from `Policy.groovy` and the fields from `Source` and `Region` objects, but after upgrading Grails to `2.4.4`, I see that the converted XML has tags only for the direct fields under `Policy.groovy` and just the top level tag for Source and Region objects, but no tags for the fields from these objects.

I have even tried with **`import grails.converters.deep.XML`**, but that didn't help.

Does anyone know how can I get the attributes from `Source` and `Region` objects to converted XML? Appreciate any pointers on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the below property in `grails-app\conf\Config.groovy` resolved it for me.

```
grails.converters.xml.default.deep = true
```

Just to add a bit of further information, the pretty-print can be turned off by setting:

```
grails.converters.xml.pretty.print = false
```